# Can't find libGLU.so.1 when trying to run VisIt

Tags: shared-libraries, libraries, hdf5

## General Problem

I have been trying to run multiple programs (VisIt and Athena) and am having similar issues on both - an inability to find shared libraries, although they do exist in a different spot.

## Code Output/Errors

Trying to run Athena gives me

```
[~athena/working]$ ~/athena/bin/athena -i athinput.blast >log
/nethome/myname/athena/bin/athena: error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.103
```

or, when running VisIt

```
[~/local/visit/bin]$ ./visit
Running: gui3.0.2
/localdata/myname/visit/3.0.2/linux-x86_64/bin/gui: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

## What I've attempted

If I use `find -iname` I can find both of these libraries

```
[~/local/anaconda2]$ find -iname 'libhdf5.so.103'
./lib/libhdf5.so.103
./pkgs/hdf5-1.10.4-nompi_h3c11f04_1106/lib/libhdf5.so.103
./pkgs/hdf5-1.10.4-hb1b8bf9_0/lib/libhdf5.so.103
```

and

```
[~/local/anaconda2]$ find -iname 'libGLU.so.1'
./lib/libGLU.so.1
./pkgs/libglu-9.0.0-hf484d3e_1/lib/libGLU.so.1
```

What do I need to do to point to them.  I've tried updating my compiler path using `export CPATH` and I've tried adding `LDLIBS := -L/nethome/sferrel6/local/anaconda2/lib -lhdf5` to the Athena Makefile (which earlier helped me find the hdf5 library)

Comment: Worth noting that `libGLU.so.1` is a symbolic link to `libGLU.so.1.3.1`, but this is also found int the same locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do I need to do to point to them

Since these libraries are not installed in the default system location(s), you *must* tell the dynamic loader where to find them. See `man ld.so` on your system.

Assuming you are on Linux, here are the ways you could do it:

1. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/anaconda2/lib`
2. Re-link `athena` binary with `-Wl,-rpath=$HOME/local/anaconda2/lib`
3. (Requires root access). Edit `/etc/ld.so.conf`, add `$HOME/local/anaconda2/lib` to it, run `/sbin/ldconfig` to update `/etc/ld.so.cache`.

Comment: Thanks.  I used #1 and it worked perfectly.  Unfortunately I'm on a university network and so can't do anything that requires root or sudo.